# How do you send a file via HTTP over tcp sockets in C?

Tags: c, sockets, http, tcp

I am implementing a client and server in C (on linux) and i want to send a text file **to a server from the client** using an HTTP PUT message.

I'm not really sure how to do this. Do I first send the HTTP request and header line over the socket, and then send the file over the socket piece by piece using a buffer? or do I need to prepend every piece of the text file with its own HTTP request and header line before I send them over?

I also read about this function called sendfile that seems like it would make this easier, but I wasn't sure how I would prepend an HTTP header and request line to the file if sendfile just sends the file straight to the socket.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Here is a minimal (but not entirely serious) example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44592/152)   of doing HTTP over low-level sockets.

Comment: @AShelly there is nothing about PUT method there!!!

Comment: If you can send a GET, you can send a PUT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I first send the HTTP request and header line over the socket, and then send the file over the socket piece by piece using a buffer?

Yes.

> or do I need to prepend every piece of the text file with its own HTTP request and header line before I send them over?

No.

> I also read about this function called sendfile that seems like it would make this easier, but I wasn't sure how I would prepend an HTTP header and request line to the file if sendfile just sends the file straight to the socket.

First send the header with a normal `send`, then call `sendfile`. However you should read the documentation, which says

> Note that a successful call to sendfile() may write fewer bytes than requested; the caller should be prepared to retry the call if 
>   there were unsent bytes.

This means that your life is not that much easier with `sendfile`. It is more efficient than a combination of `read` and `write`, but the amount of work the programmer needs to do is similar in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement HTTP transmission protocol then check this RFC http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.2

else if you want your own easy method then you can for example implement an API such `DWORD(cmdPut)+filename+'\0'+DWORD(fileLen)+fileBinaryData.`